# What is the advantage of using a hash table for storing strings in spaCy's vocabulary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, hashtable, spacy

Why not instead just have a dictionary of keys as the strings and their values as their properties/attributes? Is it a time-complexity advantage, or is there also a memory-saving advantage?

I have a basic/general understanding of hash-tables and dictionaries.

I am currently going through chapter 1 of the spaCy course course.spacy.io where it says, "Pipeline packages include a strings.json that stores the entries in the pipeline’s vocabulary and the mapping to hashes. This allows spaCy to only communicate in hashes and look up the corresponding string if needed."

I basically want some more clarification on what this looks like.

Comment: dictionaries *are hash tables*.

Comment: Got it. I assume the hash tables used in spaCy pipelines use the hashes as keys and the properties of words as their values. But I can imagine in an alternate implementation of the "en_core_web_sm" vocab where the strings themselves were stored as the keys instead. In such an implementation, would the memory usage overall not be roughly the same?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a time-complexity advantage，meanwhile reduce memory usage.

When using key-value pairs, a linear search of the entire collection is often required to find a specific value, resulting in a time complexity that increases with the size of the data set.

I think lots of NLP models use hash to increase efficiency.